# How to colorize git-status output?

Tags: git, git-config, git-status

I want to colorize git-status output so that:

```
untracked files = magenta
new files = green
modified files = blue
deleted files = red
```

I am instead seeing staged files in green and unstaged files in blue:
[image: screenshot of git-status]

My .gitconfig is setup with the following based on some searching:

```
[color]
status = auto

[color "status"]
added = green
changed = blue
untracked = magenta
deleted = red
```

Comment: Note: git 2.9.1 supports attributes italic and strike. See my edit below.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

From [git config doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-color):

```
color.status.<slot>
```

> Use customized color for status colorization. `<slot>` is one of:
>
> - `header` (the header text of the status message),
> - `added` or `updated` (files which are added but not committed),
> - `changed` (files which are changed but not added in the index),
> - `untracked` (files which are not tracked by git),
> - `branch` (the current branch),
> - `nobranch` (the color the no branch warning is shown in, defaulting to red),
> - `localBranch` or `remoteBranch` (the local and remote branch names, respectively, when branch and tracking information is displayed in the status short-format),
> - `unmerged` (files which have unmerged changes).
>
> The values of these variables may be specified as in `color.branch.<slot>`.

So this will work:

```
git config color.status.changed blue
git config color.status.untracked magenta
```

However:

```
new files = green
deleted files = red
```

Isn't possible: you need to pick one color:

- if they **are added** to the index, they will use the color for `color.status.added`.
- if they **aren't added** to the index, they will use the color for  `color.status.changed`.

Note:

Colors may also be given as numbers between 0 and 255; these use ANSI 256-color mode (but not all terminals may support this).
See "[xterm 256 colors](https://robotmoon.com/256-colors/#table-of-color-codes)" for those numbers, as noted in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795790/how-to-colorize-git-status-output/12798205#comment119918281_12798205) by [Joshua Goldberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/411282/joshua-goldberg).

---

Of course, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795790/how-to-colorize-git-status-output/12798205#comment30639337_12798205) by [elboletaire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/407456/elboletaire):

> Remember to enable coloring output if it has not been enabled previously:
>
> ```
> git config --global color.ui true
> ```

---

[Shaun Luttin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1108891/shaun-luttin) adds:

The command can also take multiple parameters in quotes. This includes two colors (foreground background) from this list:

> normal, black, red, green, yellow, blue, magenta, cyan and white;

and it also includes one attribute (style) from this list:

> bold, dim, ul, blink and reverse.

So this will work:

```
git config color.status.changed "blue normal bold"
git config color.status.header "white normal dim"
```

---

Note: with git 2.9.1 (July 2016), The output coloring scheme learned **two new attributes, *italic* and <del>strike</del>**, in addition to existing bold, reverse, etc.

See [commit 9dc3515](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9dc3515cf005639317fb95492b3157aadf056923), [commit 54590a0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/54590a0eda10ecfdc39398d662ab3f663491067e), [commit 5621068](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5621068f3d3c537b79b76201928c0b06025479ee), [commit df8e472](https://github.com/git/git/commit/df8e472cc1bbd14a60d22b0b124f07046c6e1fa2), [commit ae989a6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ae989a61dad98debe9899823ca987305f8e8020d), [commit adb3356](https://github.com/git/git/commit/adb3356664fbf15646fd90eb1d5ddd9e66ce913f), [commit 0111681](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0111681ecfe4d04a354536e62af1cde7c49e1c40) (23 Jun 2016) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3c5de5c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3c5de5c77b0718b47010b146160ecff6309f86b5), 11 Jul 2016)</sup>

It also allow "`no-`" for negating attributes

> Using "`no-bold`" rather than "`nobold`" is easier to read and more natural to type (to me, anyway, even though I was the person who introduced "`nobold`" in the first place). It's easy to allow both.

Comment: Remember to enable coloring output if it has not been enabled previously: `git config --global color.ui true`

Comment: @elboletaire good point. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Did you mean to write color.status.changed instead of color.status.modified? Or do both work?

Comment: @AndrewSwift 9 years later, reading https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-colorstatusltslotgt, this should be "changed". I have updated the answer accordingly. Thank you for this comment.

Comment: The description of legal color options is at this section of the same document: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-color — and here's [a listing of ANSI colors](https://robotmoon.com/256-colors/#table-of-color-codes). (my terminal on OSX doesn't support #ff0088)

Comment: @JoshuaGoldberg Thank you: I have restored the first link, and included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Can we also redirect the output into `less -r` and keep the color using `git status -sb --ignore-submodules=dirty | less -r` ?

Comment: @alper Reading https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/19320/7490, I would propose: `git  -c color.status=always status -sb --ignore-submodules=dirty | less -rFX`

Comment: @VonC - so how can I use `ANSI 256-color` codes? I tried: `changed = '\e[38;5;160m'` and `changed = '#d70000'`, but both give me error: `fatal: bad config variable 'color.status.changed'`

Comment: @400theCat Maybe your Git version does not support it? Could you ask a separate question, with more details (OS, OS version, git version, shell, ...)

Comment: @VonC - thank you. I have created new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69112016/how-to-use-ansi-256-color-in-gitconfig