# Git pretty format colors

Tags: git

I'm trying to set up pretty format colors for Git.  From what I can tell version 1.6.0 only recognizes red, green and blue.

```
$ git log --pretty=format:"%Credred%Creset %Cgreengreen%Creset %Cyellowyellow%Creset %Cblueblue%Creset %Cmagentamagenta%Creset %Ccyancyan%Creset %Cwhitewhite%Creset"
red green %Cyellowyellow%Creset blue %Cmagentamagenta %Ccyancyan %Cwhitewhite
```

**In addition none of the colors work with the parenthesized color format.**

Is there a way to list the available pretty format colors for Git?

Unfortunately this is on a legacy SCO OpenServer 5.0.7 machine and the last version of Git released by SCO Skunkworks was 1.6.0.3.

Comment: If your platform is obsolete, why don't you download latest git 1.8.x from git-scm.com and compile it yourself? Then it would support all the most recent features.

Comment: @mvp Well, as you said, the platform is obsolete - meaning a lack of a GNU build environment.  I'm preparing the existing application source code for migration to Linux.

Comment: Note that Git 2.3.0 (February 2015) will allow for 24-bits color values, and a better management of color attributes (bold, underline, ...). See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28256977/6309)

Comment: Git 2.26 (Q1 2020) will add the attribute "bright" to support bright aixterm colors. See [my edited answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28256977/6309)

Answer (score 175, accepted):

I do not have an old version of `git` to verify that the colors other than `red`, `blue` and `green` are supported.

Although, one thing I noticed even with the recent versions of `git` (like 1.7.10 I used) is that colors other than `red`, `green` and `blue` need to be within parentheses `()`. For `red`, `green` and `blue`, the parentheses are optional.

So give this a try:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%Credred%Creset %Cgreengreen%Creset %C(Yellow)yellow%Creset %Cblueblue%Creset %C(magenta)magenta%Creset %C(cyan)cyan%Creset %C(white)white%Creset"
```

The [list of colors](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-color) I'm aware of at least are:

```
normal
black
red
green
yellow
blue
magenta
cyan
white
```

It can be combined with one or more of these attributes:

```
bold
dim
ul
blink
reverse
italic
strike
bright  # (Git 2.26, Q1 2020, example: brightred)
```

If you're trying to change colors using `.gitconfig` you should be able to specify two colors - **foreground** and **background** and you can combine it with an attribute.

Comment: I believe you are right in that only the primary colors are supported.  The parenthesized color format does not work in this version (1.6.0.3) at all.

Comment: space seperate foreground, background & attributes like this %C(red green bold)

Comment: There are at least two other attributes: **italic** and **strike** as written in the manual here https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config and for completness reasons.

Comment: @onemorequestion No problem. I have edited the answer accordingly. I really liked your other answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/61487052/6309) by the way.

Comment: Weird, `brightred` works, but `dimmagenta` does not (Git 2.36)

Answer (score 52):

Git 2.3.0 (February 2015) will allow (thanks to [Jeff Kink (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff)):

---

- 24-bits RGB color values ([commit 17a4be2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/17a4be26060b00a867cbe54ee906fe03813470ec))

> #### `parse_color`: support 24-bit RGB values

> Some terminals (like XTerm) allow full 24-bit RGB color specifications using an extension to the regular ANSI color scheme.
> Let's allow users to specify hex RGB colors, **enabling the all-important feature of hot pink ref decorations**:
>
> ```
> git log --format="%h%C(#ff69b4)%d%C(reset) %s"
> ```

---

- a better management of color attributes:

> #### `parse_color`: recognize "`no$foo`" to clear the `$foo` attribute

> You can turn on ANSI text attributes like "reverse" by putting "reverse" in your color spec. However, you cannot ask to turn reverse off.
>
> For common cases, this does not matter. You would turn on "reverse" at the start of a colored section, and then clear all attributes with a "reset".
>
> However, you may wish to turn on some attributes, then selectively disable others. For example:
>
> ```
> git log --format="%C(bold ul yellow)%h%C(noul) %s"
> ```
>
> underlines just the hash, but without the need to re-specify the rest of the attributes.
>
> This can also help third-party programs, like [`contrib/diff-highlight`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight), that want to turn some attribute on/off without disrupting existing coloring.
>
> Note that some attribute specifications are probably nonsensical (e.g., "`bold nobold`"). We do not bother to flag such constructs, and instead let the terminal sort it out.

---

With Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), the **basic 7 colors learned the brighter counterparts (e.g. "`brightred`")**.

See [commit c444f03](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c444f032e43611b95612882cd06380866f8da0fd), [commit 1751b09](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1751b09a92e176b164a3c5527f0458d5b1154d00), [commit 4a28eb0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a28eb0ae4fc666291a6a6f84a0605ccb9279278) (21 Jan 2020) by [Eyal Soha (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 87f17d7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/87f17d790d8e350e8df1101476882f7751581ee0), 25 Feb 2020)</sup>

> ### [`color.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1751b09a92e176b164a3c5527f0458d5b1154d00): support bright aixterm colors
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Eyal Soha</sup>

> These colors are the bright variants of the 3-bit colors.
>
> Instead of 30-37 range for the foreground and 40-47 range for the background, they live in 90-97 and 100-107 range, respectively.

The [`git config` documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/87f17d790d8e350e8df1101476882f7751581ee0/Documentation/config.txt#L264-L268) now includes:

The basic colors accepted are `normal`, `black`, `red`, `green`, `yellow`,
`blue`, `magenta`, `cyan` and `white`.
The first color given is the foreground; the second is the background.

> **All the basic colors except `normal` have a bright variant that can be specified by prefixing the color with `bright`, like `brightred`.**

---

With Git 2.35 (Q1 2022), "`default`" and "`reset`" colors have been added to our palette.

See [commit de65851](https://github.com/git/git/commit/de658515ae1166577441da09fe7624769e263a3e) (26 Oct 2021), and [commit 05f1f41](https://github.com/git/git/commit/05f1f41c9b02b916a5f03c5658bec3270ac3684d), [commit aeefc18](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aeefc1866c7f98ac76aac66b92cc142b8135054e) (25 Oct 2021) by [Robert Estelle (`rwe`)](https://github.com/rwe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 15209c8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/15209c86126a00e8e26ced788019edabf100abaa), 15 Dec 2021)</sup>

> ### [`color`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/de658515ae1166577441da09fe7624769e263a3e): allow colors to be prefixed with "reset"
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Robert Estelle</sup>

> "reset" was previously treated as a standalone special color name representing `\e[m`.
> Now, it can apply to other color properties, allowing exact specifications without implicit attribute inheritance.
>
> For example, "reset green" now renders `\e[;32m`, which is interpreted as "reset everything; then set foreground to green".
> This means the background and other attributes are also reset to their defaults.
>
> Previously, this was impossible to represent in a single color: "reset" could be specified alone, or a color with attributes, but some thing like clearing a background color were impossible.
>
> There is a separate change that introduces the "default" color name to assist with that, but even then, the above could only to be represented by explicitly disabling each of the attributes:
> green default no-bold no-dim no-italic no-ul no-blink no-reverse no-strike

`config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/de658515ae1166577441da09fe7624769e263a3e/Documentation/config.txt#L291-L295):

> The pseudo-attribute `reset` resets all colors and attributes before
> applying the specified coloring. For example, `reset green` will result
> in a green foreground and default background without any active
> attributes.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/12798205/6309: git 2.9.1 supports two new attributes: *italic* and strike.

Comment: Do you know how to include the RGB colours inside a git alias? `#ff69b4` works on the command line but not in an alias, because `#` starts a comment

Comment: @TimMalone I didn't test it yet, but the config man page says "Leading whitespaces after name `=`, the remainder of the line after the first comment character `#` or `;`, and trailing whitespaces of the line are discarded **unless they are enclosed in double quotes**. "

Comment: @TimMalone Put the whole alias in `"`-quotes and then the `#` won't be special.

Comment: @VonC, I get weird characters when I pipe those `git log` command outputs to a text or clip. It looks like this happens when colors and attributes are used with `--format`. Any idea why or fix for this?

Comment: @hIpPy No idea just yet: could you detail your issue in a new question (with the OS used, Git version used and shell used)

Answer (score 10):

Share my git log format:

```bash
$ git log --graph --pretty=format:'%C(magenta)%h%Creset -%C(red)%d%Creset %s %C(dim green)(%cr) %C(cyan)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit
```

You can also add an alias into *~/.gitconfig*:

```ini
[alias]
    logs  = log --graph --pretty=format:'%C(magenta)%h%Creset -%C(red)%d%Creset %s %C(dim green)(%cr) %C(cyan)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit
```

then you can use alias as you define in `~/.gitconfig`.

```bash
$ git logs
```

Comment: The question is asking how to find out git's pretty format colors.

Answer (score 6):

Here are two aliases that I wrote, once I understood the syntax of using custom hexadecimal color values as shown in [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28256977/241211).

There are four versions. The only difference is the `--graph` directive, and the `f` versions will also show you files that were added, deleted, or modified:

```ini
[alias]
    lg = log --graph --pretty=format:"%C(#cd9a00)%h\\%C(#0080ff)\\ <%an>\\ %C(#17b062)(%cr)\\ %d\\%C(#c0d6de)%s"    
    l1 = log         --pretty=format:"%C(#cd9a00)%h\\%C(#0080ff)\\ <%an>\\ %C(#17b062)(%cr)\\ %d\\%C(#c0d6de)%s"    
    lgf = log --name-status --graph --pretty=format:"%C(#cd9a00)%h\\%C(#0080ff)\\ <%an>\\ %C(#17b062)(%cr)\\ %d\\%C(#c0d6de)%s" 
    l1f = log --name-status         --pretty=format:"%C(#cd9a00)%h\\%C(#0080ff)\\ <%an>\\ %C(#17b062)(%cr)\\ %d\\%C(#c0d6de)%s"
```

I used [ColorHexa](https://www.colorhexa.com/) to pick the exact colors I wanted and then copied the hex value from it.

For Windows, open up your *.gitconfig* file that resides in your *C:\Users\YourUserName* folder and add an alias section as depicted above.

Answer (score 4):

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and I was able to use Xiaofei HAN's suggestions.

For beginner trying to complete this, I had the best luck by editing the .gitconfig.

```
nano ~/.gitconfig
```

paste [alias] block from above under the existing text

CTRL + O (to write out) + CTRL + X (to close nano)

After doing this, to see the pretty colors you can use

```
git logs
```

using

'git log' will get you the view without the colors,

same for 'git logs --oneline', except that one will show the flourish on the side

thank you, i hope this helps someone