# using hex color code in git log and gitconfig alias

Tags: git

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28256977/2005559) reply about hex color-code in git log format, I tried to do the same. While directly using that in terminal, it is working fine:

```
$git log --format="%h%C(#ff69b4)%d%C(reset) %s"|head -1
dc814e3 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Compilation help added
```

Problem arises if I add `log --format="%h%C(#ff69b4)%d%C(reset) %s"` part in alias in `.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
  ll =log --format="%h%C(#ff69b4)%d%C(reset) %s"
```

which gives error:

```
$git ll
fatal: ambiguous argument '%s': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

A search gives a solution to the same type of problem [here](https://superuser.com/a/273597/325819): suggesting a trial of escaping the `"` with `\"`.

If I do this, e.g.

```
[alias]
  ll =log --format=\"%h%C(#ff69b4)%d%C(reset) %s\"
```

I get error:

```
git ll
fatal: Bad alias.ll string: unclosed quote
```

I am using:

```
$echo $TERM; echo $SHELL; git --version
xterm-256color
/bin/bash
git version 2.4.3
```

what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

To complete [Roman's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32490864/6224056) answer, the problem actually lies in the fact that the alias needs to be properly enclosed in quotes :

What we have :

```
ll =log --format=\"%h%C(#ff69b4)%d%C(reset) %s\"
```

What we need :

```
ll ="log --format=\"%h%C(#ff69b4)%d%C(reset) %s\""
    ^                                            ^
```

As simple as that !

Answer (score 1):

Avoid editing `.gitconfig` by hand, just use

```
git config --global alias.ll 'log --format="%h%C(#ff69b4)%d%C(reset) %s"'
```

Comment: Do note that if you break into the shell with `!`, then that may need to be escaped as your shell may interpret that as a substitution request for the previous command's parameter, as do any other special chars such as `$` or additional quotes used.

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me.

This works fine in terminal:

```
git log --format="%h%C(#ff69b4)%d%C(reset) %s"
```

but not in **.gitconfig**

In .gitconfig file, I put this simple quotes, and works fine to me:

```
git log --format='"%h%C(#ff69b4)%d%C(reset) %s"'
```

In my opinion, this behavior will change based on your system.
You will have to experiment to get the right combination on your system.