# What does origin/main and origin/HEAD mean in my commit, and why are they red?

Tags: git, version-control, terminology, distributed

I've started using Git, and I've recently learned to use

```
git log --all --graph
```

to look at my commit history, and I noticed some details that I find worrying. For example, the line to the left is red, which indicates to me that something is wrong. Moreover just after the name of the commit there is some text which I have trouble interpreting. I think that `HEAD -> main` means that the HEAD is pointing to main. But then there are 2 more strings (also in red indicating something is wrong) which I think are remotes?

Is the line to the left indicating something is wrong, or am I reading it wrong? What does the text next to the commit number mean? What do the three parts mean? Is there something wrong, and if so how can I fix it?

This is the topmost line in my log. What does `origin/main` and `origin/HEAD` mean and why are they red?

```
* commit 9bee2dac5bb71b843022409d33a46af52be217d4 (HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/HEAD)
```

Comment: This is actually a situation where a screenshot of the relevant portion of the graph would be useful.

Comment: "What does origin/main and origin/HEAD mean" okay, if you don't know that, you don't really know enough about Git basics to get started. I suggest you read my intro: https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/

Comment: @matt to be specific, what do they mean in my commit?

Comment: They are not "in" your commit. They are each pointing to your commit (at this moment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git is really all about *commits*.  The commits have hash IDs:

> ```
> * commit 9bee2dac5bb71b843022409d33a46af52be217d4 (...)
> ```

That `9bee...7d4` thing there is the hash ID for your *latest* commit on your `main` branch.  The commit that *is* the latest will change over time, as you and others add new commits, but for now, `9bee2da...` is the latest.

If Git didn't have easier ways to name commits, this would drive all the humans working with Git insane.  ([Some say](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mswaPXFTcNE) that Git does that anyway.)  Imagine having to memorize these big ugly random-looking things just to get your commits!  But you don't have to do that: Git will save the hash ID of the *latest* commit of each of your branches, in a *branch name*.

Repositories, then, consist primarily of two databases: one—usually the biggest—holds the *commits* and supporting internal Git objects.  These all have hash IDs; the commits' hash IDs are the ones you will deal with.  To help you—and Git itself—*find* the commit and other hash IDs, the repository *also* stores a bunch of names: branch names, tag names, `refs/stash` for `git stash`, and so on.  Each name in this big table of names stores one hash ID, and that's the other database in a repository: a set of <name, hash-ID> pairs.  Some of these names are *branch* names, and those are the branches in the repository.

(The objects in the objects database are fully read-only: once you make a commit you can *never change it*.  The *names* in the *names* database store hash IDs, but the stored hash IDs can be replaced at any time, or even deleted and/or new names created.  So the *names* change over time, to select the *latest* commit.  We'll skip all the rest of the details here, though they do matter.)

Git isn't just a version control system (VCS) though: it's a *distributed* VCS.  Git does this distribution trick by letting us *copy a repository*.  We use `git clone` to do that.  When we clone someone else's Git repository, we get *all their commits*<sup>1</sup> and *none of their branches*.  The hash IDs of their commits are the hash IDs of *our* commits at this point: the hash ID of any one commit is *totally unique* to *that particular commit*, and every Git repository that has *that* commit, uses *that* hash ID for it.  That hash ID is now reserved for *that* commit.  (This is why they're so big and ugly: that way, that there's always a fresh new ID available for all of *your* new commits.)

To remember their *branch* names, our Git, in our clone, creates or updates our own *remote-tracking names*.  Our Git software remembers the URL we used to *make* the clone, using a shorter (than a URL) name.  There's a standard first name here, `origin`, which everybody uses,<sup>2</sup> so the URL for *their* Git repository is stored under the name `origin`.  Git then uses that *same name* to stick in front of each of their *branch* names: their `main` becomes our `origin/main`, their `develop` (if they have one) becomes our `origin/develop`, and so on.

So your `origin/*` names are simply a reflection of the fact that the repository you cloned has some *branch* names.  Their branch names = your remote-tracking names, because your Git sees their names and changes them, to let your repository remember their branches.

Because you and they share the *commits*—you got all your commits *from* them—their `origin/main` remembers commit hash ID `9bee2da...`.  Once your `git clone` operation has copied their commits and modified their branch names, your own Git software creates *one new branch* in *your* repository.  The name your Git used here was `main`.<sup>3</sup>  So your Git created your own `main` to match your `origin/main` that your Git uses to remember their `main`.

That means you have:

- the branch name `main`: this is *your* name for (at the moment) commit `9bee2da...`;
- the remote-tracking name `origin/main`: this is *your* copy of *their* branch name that, the last time your Git talked with their Git software and repository, named commit `9bee2da...`.

So when you run `git log`, your Git:

1. uses the name `main` to find `9bee2da...`;
2. uses the hash ID `9bee2da...` to find the commit;
3. *shows* the commit `9bee2da...`;
4. adds, in parentheses, the *decorations* you saw: some in green, some in red.

(There's actually a step before step 1: your Git uses `HEAD` to find `main`.  But we're leaving that part out for now.)

---

<sup>1</sup>We *can* get less than all commits, but "copy all commits" is the way to think about this at first, at least.

<sup>2</sup>You *can* use something else if you want.  If you do, your remote-tracking names will be a little different.  But everyone else will *expect* to see `origin`, so there is no point to doing extra work to use a different name.

<sup>3</sup>You tell your Git, at `git clone` time, which of their branch names you want your Git to copy.  To select their `develop`, for instance, you'd run `git clone -b develop ...`.  If you don't pick a branch name, your Git asks their Git which name *they* recommend, and usually that's their main or master or whatever.

---

#### Green and red, but nothing wrong

> For example, the line to the left is red, which indicates to me that something is wrong.

No: Git just uses eight colors by default, namely `red`, `green`, `blue`, `yellow`, `cyan`, `magenta`, `black`, and `white`.  This is all that was commonly available 20 years ago.  There are some additional words allowed here, and modern Git can use 24-bit color if it's supported by your terminal (see [Git pretty format colors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15458237/1256452)).  For the line-drawing part (see [Pretty Git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/1256452)), Git starts with red (and there's no easy way to configure this).

> I think that HEAD -> main means that the HEAD is pointing to main.

That's correct: the special name `HEAD`—which is not actually a *branch* name—normally holds the name of some branch; when it does, we say that the name `HEAD` is *attached to*, or *points to* that branch name.

> But then there are 2 more strings (also in red indicating something is wrong) which I think are remotes?

These are the *remote-tracking names* I mentioned above.  `git branch -a` will show both branch names (which are always local, so "local branch" is redundant, like saying "ATM machine", but sometimes it feels appropriate anyway) and remote-tracking names; it prints the branch names in green by default, and the remote-tracking names in red by default.  I'm not sure if this is meant as a mnemonic device ("red = remote"), but you can use it as one, if you like.  (But then what does green equal?  "Glocal" sounds way too much like "global". )

The second red name is `origin/HEAD`: this is your Git's copy of the other Git's `HEAD`, more or less.  However, Git doesn't update it, the way it updates remote-tracking names.<sup>4</sup>  If you think their `HEAD` may have changed, you can run `git remote set-head origin --auto` to have your Git call up their Git and find where their `HEAD` is now.  But there's very little use for `origin/HEAD` in my opinion, so I never bother.

---

<sup>4</sup>Every time you run `git fetch origin`, your Git calls up their Git again, using the URL Git saved under the name `origin`, and picks up any new commits they have, that you don't, and updates your remote-tracking names based on their branch names.  In fact, `git clone` is really just shorthand for running `git init` + `git remote add origin ...` + `git fetch origin` + a few more steps: it's the `git fetch` step that creates all your remote-tracking names initially, and gets all their commits initially.  Since `git fetch` defaults to *get the commits they have that I don't*, and initially you have no commits, it initially gets all their commits.  Since it doesn't create or update any *branch* names—only remote-tracking names—that's why `git clone` copies all their commits and none of their branches.